# JMS (ActiveMQ) Performance

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a Java application with a number of components communicating via JMS (ActiveMQ). Currently, the application and the JMS Hub are on the same server, although we eventually plan to split out the components for scalability. We have significant issues with performance, all seemingly around JMS, most notably, and the focus of this question, is the amount of time it is taking to publish a message to a topic.

We have around 50 dynamically created topics used for communication between the components of the application. One component reads records from a table and processes them one at a time, the processing involves creating a JMS object message and publishing it to one of the topics. This processing could not keep up with the rate at which records were being written to the source table ~23/sec, so we changed the processing to create the JMS object message and add it to a queue. A new thread was created which reads from this queue and published the message to the appropriate topic. Obviously, this does not speed the processing up, but it did allow us to see how far behind we were getting by looking at the size of the queue.

At the start of the day, no messages are going through the whole system, this quickly ramps up from 1560000 (433/sec) messages through the hub in the first hour to 2100000 (582/sec) in the 3rd hour, and then staying at that level. At the start of the first hour, the message publishing from the component reading records from the database table keeps up, but by the end of that hour there are 2000 messages in the queue waiting to be sent and by the 3rd hour the queue has 9000 messages in it.

Below are the appropriate sections of the code which send the JMS messages. Any advice on what we are doing wrong or how we can improve this performance are much appreciated. Looking at stats on the web, JMS should be able to easily handle ~1000-2000 large messages/sec or ~10000 small messages/sec. Our messages are around 500 bytes each, so I imagine sit somewhere in the middle of that scale.

Code for getting the publisher:

```java
private JmsSessionPublisher getJmsSessionPublisher(String topicName) throws JMSException {
    if (!this.topicPublishers.containsKey(topicName)) {
        TopicSession pubSession = (ActiveMQTopicSession) topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        ActiveMQTopic topic = getTopic(topicName, pubSession);

        // Create a JMS publisher and subscriber
        TopicPublisher publisher = pubSession.createPublisher(topic);

        this.topicPublishers.put(topicName, new JmsSessionPublisher(pubSession, publisher));
    }
    return this.topicPublishers.get(topicName);
}
```

Sending the message:

```java
JmsSessionPublisher jmsSessionPublisher = getJmsSessionPublisher(topicName);
    
ObjectMessage objMessage = jmsSessionPublisher.getSession().createObjectMessage(messageObj);
objMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationID);
objMessage.setJMSTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
jmsSessionPublisher.getPublisher().publish(objMessage, false, 4, 0);
```

Code which adds messages to the queue:

```java
List<EventQueue> events = eventQueueDao.getNonProcessedEvents();
for (EventQueue eventRow : events) {
    IEvent event = eventRow.getEvent();
    AbstractEventFactory.EventType eventType = AbstractEventFactory.EventType.valueOf(event.getEventType());
    String topic = event.getTopicName() + topicSuffix;
    EventMsgPayload eventMsg = AbstractEventFactory.getFactory(eventType).getEventMsgPayload(event);
    synchronized (queue) {
        queue.add(new QueueElement(eventRow.getEventId(), topic, eventMsg));
        queue.notify();
    }
}
```

Code in the thread removing items from the queue:

```java
jmsSessionFactory.publishMessageToTopic(e.getTopic(), e.getEventMsg(), Integer.toString(e.getEventMsg().hashCode()));
```

The `publishMessageToTopic` executes the 'Sending the message' code above.

Other JMS implementations are an option if the consensus is that ActiveMQ may not be the best option.

Comment: Are you using transactions?  What configuration do you have for the queues?  Are they really queues?  Or topics?  So many questions :).  What version of ActiveMQ?  Standalone?  On an App server?

Comment: We don't explicitly use transactions unless they are used by default. We don't create any configuration on the hub and the Topics are dynamically created using: topic = (ActiveMQTopic) this.initialContext.lookup("dynamicTopics/" + topicName); We use ActiveMQ version 5.3.2 running in a standalone instance.

Comment: So what's up with this issue? Did you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

We do not use ActiveMQ, but we ran into similar issues, we discovered that the issues were with the back-end processing and not with the Java side. There could be multiple issues here:

1. The program processing the messages from the queue could be slow (e.g. CICS on mainframe) it might not be able to keep up with the messages that are sent to the queue. One possible solution for this is to increase the processing power (or optimize the back end code which processes the messages)
2. Check the messages on the queue, sometimes there are are lots of uncommitted poison messages on the queue, we use a separate queue for such messages.

Comment: I don't think there is a processing issue. The application is running on a 4 CPU server and runs at about 50% peeking no higher than 70%. The code which adds the messages to the queue and pulls them off is very simple. I have added it to my post.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear where you are experiencing the slow performance, but it sounds like what you are describing is slowness in publishing the messages. Are you creating a new publisher every time you publish a message? If so, this is terribly inefficient and you should consider creating one publisher and use it over and over to send messages. Furthermore, if you are sending persistent messages, then you are probably using synchronous sends to the broker. You might want to consider using asynchronous sends to speed things up. For more info, see the doc about [Async Sends](http://activemq.apache.org/async-sends.html)

Also, how is the performance of the consumers? How many consumers are being used? Are they able to keep pace with the rate at which messages are being published?

Additionally, what is the broker configuration that you are using? Has it been tuned at all?

Bruce

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, there is one very very important advice missing:

- Investigate the amount of topics and queues that you have.

ActiveMQ keeps subscription topics in separate threads. Particularly, when you have large amounts of different topics, this will drag down any server. Think about using JMS selectors instead.

I ran into a similar situation where I had thousands of market data messages per second. When I naively dumped each message into a market instrument specific channel, the server was able to stand about an hour before it was spitting out error messages to the message producers. I changed the design to have ONE channel "MARKET_DATA" and I then set header properties on all produced messages and set a selector on the consumer side to select just the messages that I want. Note that my selector is in SQL like syntax and runs on the server though ... (yeah, let's skip the CEP marketing hype bashing) ...